# delete matched characters using regex in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to write a regex for the following text:

```
"How can you restate your point (something like: \"<font>First</font>\") as a clear topic?"
```

that keeps whatever is between the

```
\" \"
```

characters (in this case `<font>First</font>`

I came up with this:

`/"How can you restate your point \(something like: |\) as a clear topic\?"/`

but how do I get ruby to remove the unwanted surrounding text and only return `<font>First</font>`?

Comment: A regex does not keep anything; a regex does not do anything. It is just an object. A method (that uses a regex) may do something, as well as keep something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lookbehind, lookahead and making what is greedy, lazy.

```
 str[/(?<=\").+?(?=\")/] #=> "<font>First</font>"
```

Comment: [`s[/"([^"]+)"/, 1]`](http://ideone.com/73bgax) version looks tidier to me.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I agree. That's so good that I shan't forget it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have strings just like that, you can `.split` and get the first:

```
> str.split(/"/)[1]
=> "<font>First</font>"
```

Comment: ..or  `str.split('"')[1]`. Personally, I only use a regex when a string won't do.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can use a regular expression, but you don't need to:

```
str = "How can you restate (like: \"<font>First</font>\") as a clear topic?"

str[str.index('"')+1...str.rindex('"')]
  #=> "<font>First</font>"
```

or, for those like me who never use three dots:

```
str[str.index('"')+1..str.rindex('"')-1]
```